# formula error when having empty DataSource

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using crystal reports in my asp.net application of vs2012.
I have a formula in group of datasource
that is:

if( {PB_Portal_Reports_RestrictionRepClass.Amount}>0)then
  t:= ToText({PB_Portal_Reports_RestrictionRepClass.Amount}) +" "+{PB_Portal_Reports_RestrictionRepClass.Currency}
else 
  t:= "xxx";

when I have at least one record the report is working as needed, but when I pass list with number of records =0, then I have an error

> A string is required here.
>   Details: errorKindError in File CollectionListReport {E78D7A32-A1D9-4C39-B11A-C333992049DC}.rpt:
>   Error in formula  amn: 
>   'if( {PB_Portal_Reports_RestrictionRepClass.Amount}>0)then'
>   A string is required here.
>   Details: errorKind

I tried to use isnull, or type conversion, or even tried to check first some other variable "has_data" and only then try to do this comparision but still had no luck in solving this error,
please help me

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am running into the same issue. I am getting a "Field is not known" exception though, but same problem.

Comment: No actually I didn't. My workaround was not using formula. I put the logic I needed in dataset generation

Answer (score 0):

Andrei,

Why are you converting to text here?

```
 t:= ToText({PB_Portal_Reports_RestrictionRepClass.Amount})
```

I think you should be fine with just using

`t:=({PB_Portal_Reports_RestrictionRepClass.Amount})`

Give that a try and let me know if it works.

Cheers,

Chris

Comment: no it is not working, actually it is one of my numerous variation of this code, i tried with different variables but mostly without them, I just returned value

Comment: In your report options (Crystal Reports -> Report -> Report Options) see if you have "Convert Database NULL values to default" and "Convert other NULL values to default" checked. That may help.