# Crystal report display no data record error when using formula

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

I have [Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V4ZL.jpg) that load and  set source for my report, and model Student that contain : id, name, mark
 and my [report design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBLt8.jpg) 
 i want display message if no record found 
But the problem happen when  `rd.SetDataSource(rptSource);` have `count = 0` in controller. The Exception point to Formula @toword =>  "Error in formula toword" that have code :

```
If {CR_With_MVC_Models_Student.mark}  >= 50  and 
{CR_With_MVC_Models_Student.mark} < 70 Then
    "average"
Else If {CR_With_MVC_Models_Student.mark} < 50 Then
    "Not Good"
Else iF {CR_With_MVC_Models_Student.mark} >= 70 Then
    "Good"
```

is anyway that i keep using formula `@toword` and pass away from that error

Comment: i think i have same problem with [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185763/formula-error-when-having-empty-datasource) .

Comment: can you post the error here?

Comment: this cause is if i have no record in my report the formula is no meaning so i re-construct model to display what i want to show in report